# Magento2 Create Order in Backend always same store

Tags: magento2, backend

I have a Magento2 Installation with multiple Stores. Each Store has its own countries which are allowed to be selected. E.G. The Countries in Store 1 are disabled in store 2, and same behaviour the other way around.

So when i want to create a new order in the backend, i first have to select a store as you know, afterwards the address form is loaded, with the options delivered by the selected store (e.g. allowed countries, products whithin selected store etc.)

But there's one big issue: nomatter which store i choose, the form has always the same allowed countries even if they are explicitly disabled for the selected store.

So i started debugging the HTML generated on this page and found the problem.
The "selected" Store ID in this Form is always **0** Nomatter which store i choose. And i don't even have a Store with ID 0. I just know that in Magento2 Store ID 0 is some kind of imaginary Store, like for default values etc. but i am not really sure.

The Bug is on the following backend url:

test.com/admin/sales/order_create/

Has anyone of you experienced this bug or has an idea how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: What is the version of your Magento ? I test it on Magento 2.1.2 without any problem.

Comment: Magento ver. 2.1.0

Comment: You can try to use the latest version and check realese notes.

Comment: Can you check the store_id header parameter of this ajax call : http://yourdomain.local/index.php/admin/sales/order_create/loadBlock/key/c0a46ee474e37ff788396375c76694b06e9021fae3e76339334f29018b810a4f/block/billing_method,shipping_address,totals,giftmessage,items,shipping_method,shipping_address?isAjax=true

Comment: customer_id:false
store_id:1
currency_id:false
form_key:4RUjRaMh5q1DkrUY
payment[method]:free
json:true

Comment: Ok so your store_id is correct. I reproduice your bug when I refresh the page on the customer selection. Then the store is set to 0 them some problem occurs. I think it is a bug in Magento application. You can create an issue on their support.

Comment: Try this workaround on javascript console : order.setStoreId('1')

Comment: I will create a ticket on Magento EE support. Reproduice: Refresh the page after cancel the order creation, then select the store, then no customer is selected

Comment: I tried order.setStoreId() but it didn't help, it does change the store, but the countries are still the same. do you know where magento gets the country list for the html dropdown?

Comment: Please check that you have set correctly the allow countries from your store scope config. Then refresh all the cache.

Comment: The address form is render here : vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Shipping/Address.php and vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/address.phtml

Comment: @FranckGarnier Did you open a Ticket? Can you send me the link?

Comment: It is an internal ticket throught Magento EE support, I keep you updated, the ticket is escalated.